# How to redirect to home page using nodejs app and middleware in a SPA?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am building a single survey app using `express` and `handlebars` as view engine. I created a html template for logo using *partials* method, which redirects to home page `('/')`.

In my `src` folder I created an `index.js` file that contains some functions for each route, I am using `page` **module** in order to get html tags from each route.

When I am in survey route `localhost.../survey` the logo doesn't redirects to home page, it shows the main url, but it doesn't load the page view.

First, I fixed the problem calling `next()` function. However, since I need to use a middleware to load user data in `ctx` param, now `next()` function has not been helpful for this purpose.

I am using this code:

```
// config routes
page('/', loadMember, (ctx, next) => {
  next()
})

function loadMember (ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.auth) {
    next()
  } else {
    axios
      .get('/test.json')
      .then((res) => {
        let response = res.data
        if (response.email) {
          ctx.auth = response
        } else {
          ctx.auth = false
        }

          next()
        })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
      })
  }
}
```

I have tried to change `next()` function in different ways, however I am not getting a success redirection.

If I remove `loadMember` middleware, for example:

```
page('/', (ctx, next) => {
  next()
})
```

...redirection works well. The problem is in middleware for sure. am I missing something in middleware, is `next()` function called ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` in loadMember function is not indented in the right place in order to call next step in your code.

Change order:

```
function loadMember (ctx, next) {
  if (ctx.auth) {
    next()
  } else {
    axios
      .get('/test.json')
      .then((res) => {
        let response = res.data
        if (response.email) {
          ctx.auth = response
        } else {
          ctx.auth = false
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })

    next() // HERE
  }
}
```